# Objective-C: Check Firewall status in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, firewall

My objective-c app needs to be aware if the firewall in OSX is running, so it can tell the user to turn it off or create a new rule.

Also, is it possible to create rules directly from my app so users never need to handle networking issues?

John

Comment: What if the firewall is on a router? Your users will just have to deal with the firewall on their own.

Answer (score 5):

I am writing a function that will provide you the status of OSX firewall :)

```
-(BOOL)getFirewallStatus{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSSystemDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",path,@"Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist"];

    path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/System"
                                           withString:@""];




    NSDictionary* _dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    // firewall status
    int status = [[_dictionary valueForKey:@"globalstate"] integerValue];

    if (status == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: Still works in 2022 with Monterey

Answer (score 1):

If your application is being run by the user (i.e., double-clicked in the Finder), any attempt by your application to create a socket listener will prompt the user to allow/deny that listener - and subsequently adjust the firewall settings accordingly - without any programmatic intervention on the part of your application.

If the firewall in question is your router (a problem I recently had to deal with), you have a few options. The best supported option is Bonjour/mDNSResponder (as long as you don't want to support a double-nat'ed situation). Apple provides an Objective-C wrapper application around the rather obtuse dns_sd.h:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PortMapper/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007879-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Going the 3rd party route, take a look at TCM Port Mapper. It uses some deprecated features and it'll take a bit of effort to get it running with ARC support (if that's important to you).

http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/

Both support UPnP and NAT-PMP.

Finally, if your application is running as a daemon (without a user interface), you're going to have to become acquainted with ipfw. Brace yourself. Google for "ipfw os x". StackOverflow is preventing me from posting more than two links. Brilliant.

Hope this helps....