# How to get Firewall Status in Swift on Mac OS?

Tags: swift, macos, firewall

I spent two days to get firewall status of mac os in swift.
I did some research and googled. So I knew to read globalstate key of com.apple.alf.plist.
I could find the code in objective-c
[Objective-C: Check Firewall status in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699349/objective-c-check-firewall-status-in-osx)
But it does not work.
I tried to read com.apple.alf.plist in swift as below.

```
let path = "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist"
let _dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

But _dictionary is nil.

My MacOS is Mojave 10.14.6 and Swift is 5.

I will appreciate any solution.

Comment: That's not how you read the content of a plist file in Swift.  Search for how to read plist in Swift.

Comment: But I dont think the problem is related to what you said.
It does not seem to be allowed to read com.apple.alf.plist.
In order to read it, requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access. How to solve the user rights problem.

Comment: You are not allowed to access any file without user's consent with a sandboxed application.  That's basics in developing a Cocoa application.

Comment: It is first time for me to develop mac OS application. There are many things that I don't know. Could you kindly explain how to grant com.apple.alf.plist read access in a sandboxed application?

Comment: Don't take a shortcut by relying on others.  Look it up for yourself.